# REST Path params conflicting with resource path?

Tags: java, api, rest, jax-rs

This question came up while I was building a backend using JAX-RS but this can really apply to any REST API.

How does JAX-RS handle paths that might conflict due to param path variables? Suppose you have

```
@POST
@Path('createBox/{boxName}')
foo()

@POST
@Path('createBox/small')
bar()
```

And someone wants to call the first endpoint with a path param argument of `small`. What happens in this case? If `foo()` and `bar()` had different parmas (maybe like `@FormParam`) would that help differentiate? What if they were exactly the same with no arguments? Is the behavior non-deterministic?

Comment: Did you try it out? :)

Answer (score 1):

Reference : **RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0, 2nd Edition** by Bill Burke

1. `"/customers/{id : .+}` <-- getCustomer
2. `"/customers/{id : .+}/address"`  <-- getAddress

**Precedence rules**

The JAX-RS specification has defined strict sorting and precedence rules for matching URI expressions and is based on a most specific match wins algorithm.

1. The primary key of the sort is the number of literal characters in the full URI matching pattern and is in descending order ( 11 in getCustomer vs 18 in getAddress)
2. The secondary key of the sort is the number of template expressions embedded within the pattern—that is, `{id}` or `{id : .+}`. This sort is in descending order.
3. The tertiary key of the sort is the number of nondefault template expressions. A default template expression is one that does not define a regular expression—that is, `{id}`

**Your example:**

`bar()` wins because as per rule 1, it has more literal characters